# Sub total & total with aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extend my sql query that returns sub totals & totals. Is there a way to return both sub totals and grand total with this query:

I have data like this:

```
Department Employee Sal
A          Jack     1000          
A          Pack     1000          
A          Dack     1000          
B          BEN     1000          
B          HEN     1000          
C          SIN     1000
```

I Want this, i.e Subtotal & Total for all the Department

```
Department Employee Sal
A          Jack     1000          
A          Pack     1000          
A          Dack     1000      
A_Sub_Total         3000      
B          BEN      1000          
B          MAT      1000          
B_Sub_Total         2000      
C          SIN      1000  
C_Sub_Total         1000    
Total               6000
```

I tried to use compute function i.e "Compute Sum(Sal) by Department"
it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT [Department], [Employee], [Sal]
FROM #mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT [Department] + '_Sub_Total',
       NULL,
       SUM([Sal]) AS Sal
FROM #mytable
GROUP BY [Department] 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', NULL, SUM([Sal]) AS Sal
FROM #mytable 
ORDER BY Department
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WITH ROLLUP.

```
SELECT ISNULL(Department, 'Total'), ISNULL(Employee, Department + '_Sub_Total'), SUM(Sal) AS Sal FROM [test] GROUP BY Department, Employee WITH ROLLUP
```